# RXJS, and the keyword from. That Turn an array, promise, or iterable into an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

So I have a short question about the keyword from from rxjs.

I see this piece of code:

```
 sensorMetadataCollection$ = from(this.sensorMetadataService.getMetadata());
```

but getMetadata is already an observable:

```
 public getMetadata(observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<SensorMetadataCollectionDto>;
```

So is the keyword from needed in this case?

Thank you

Comment: No, `from()` is usefull typically when you want to turn arrays or Promises into Observables.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought that. Oke, solved

Comment: Or static items into observables, i.e. `from([x, y, z])`